# Path of newly added image files in IBM Connections

Tags: ibm-connections

I have been trying to customize IBM Connections UI and have been able to insert and execute code in `header.jsp` thanks to the material available on the web. 
The problem is if I add a new image file under the themes directory in `<IBM_CONNECTIONS>\data\shared\customization\themes\images`, how do I reference this image in `header.jsp`? Surely I cannot use an absolute path here which is `<IBM_CONNECTIONS>/connections/resources/web/com.ibm.lconn.core.styles.oneui3/images/myimage.png`.
Similarly I would like to add a new JavaScript, but I am not able to figure out how to give its relative path in `header.jsp`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can use that, you just need to turn on CUSTOMIZATION_DEBUG variable which is in your WAS variable, otherwise you need to iterate your version #

Answer (score 3):

The `<CONNECTIONS_CUSTOMIZATION_PATH>/themes` directory should only be used to override images referenced by existing stylesheets, or add new images for custom stylesheets. If all you need is to display an image, the recommended location is `<CONNECTIONS_CUSTOMIZATION_PATH>/common/images` (create subdirectories if necessary). The image will be available under every application's context root, e.g. `/files/images/myimage.png`

Answer (score 0):

claudiopro, your solution works with **/files/images/myimage.png** and  **/profiles/images/myimage.png**  and so on. But what about main /homepage/
The url /homepage/images/myimage.png is not working. 
Do you know how to avoid that?

Do you also know where the solution you provided is documented in IBM Knowledge Center?
In documentation of Connections 5.0 there are few pages about images and CSS custiomizations but some of those solutions are not even working, some are in contraty with each other...